# How reliable is $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] at capturing query strings?

Tags: php, query-string

From what I've read, it seems that `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` won't *always* return query strings properly, but does anyone have a good sense of what the success rate is? Will it work in the majority of cases for the average client?

What, if anything, would cause `REQUEST_URI` to not be populated or not include the query string?

Comment: Typically it's either 0% or 100%. Depends on the server.

Comment: @WesleyMurch: So it's completely up to the server? It seems to be working for me. Does that mean it's safe to assume it should work for any user?

Comment: I have never seen a server not populating this correctly, maybe you are talking about a CLI script?

Comment: @PlatinumAzure: I just need to get the URL including the query string. Can I use `$_GET` for this?

Comment: If it works for you it will work for any user using the same server.

Comment: @David: Yes, if it works on a particular server you can be pretty sure it wil work 100% of the time. I'm not sure what causes it to not be populated, so that might be a better question to ask. I'm going to take the liberty to edit that into your question, feel free to rollback the edit if you wish.

Comment: I wasn't aware you needed the URL. `$_GET` allows you to get the keys and values in the query string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You asked:

> What, if anything, would cause REQUEST_URI to not be populated?

Answers that I can think of:

1. The web server provides all the `$_SERVER` values to PHP, so if the server doesn't provide them, then they won't be set. This is highly unlikely with any decent web server, but is possible.
2. If you run a PHP program from the command line, it won't have any `$_SERVER` values. (in case you're not worried about this, bear in mind that unit tests are typically run from a command line, so it does matter if you're following best practices and writing unit tests)

Answer (score 1):

> What, if anything, would cause REQUEST_URI to not be populated?

A Google search seems to indicate this to have been the case with IIS (but what was true then, might not be now):

```
https://bugs.launchpad.net/xibo/+bug/654536
```

(there is an article about a fix for IIS: http://davidwalsh.name/iis-php-server-request_uri )

as well as other cases in which the "server" was not your *standard* web server (e.g. debugging server plugin, etc.).

It was noticed **but considered a bug** in less known or old versions of web servers (lighthttpd, iPlanet Web Server 7.0).

So I believe you can be reasonably sure that the variable is always going to be populated. Of course, it would be wise to prepare a very small test script to run at the customer's site as early as possible in order to be forewarned.